# E: Unable to locate package

Tags: 13.04, software-installation, my-weather-indicator

I'd like to install a program called my weather indicator, i installed via terminal:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
$ sudo apt-get update
```

And finaly it's ready to install my-weather-indicator package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package my-weather-indicator
```

I try add repo and update again but still no result, could anyone help me solve this problem ?

Comment: That package isn't available for raring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, 13.04 has reached End-Of-Life, and it is recommended that you upgrade to Saucy.

Second, the PPA doesn't contain any packages for Raring anymore (most likely because it is EOL), and so you can't install `my-weather-indicator`.